date issues when storing and accessing date from firebase datastore
I have an app built using Ionic angular and Google Firebase. I use fire store and store dates using the method  (new Date()).getTime() from my code. One of the things I am facing is the issue when I get this date back and try to do some calculations.
In my case, I store a lot of objects with dates as 1 Jan 2024. I do it as follows:
Date:number
...
this.Date = moment().startOf('year').valueOf()

And when I retrieve it back from firebase do things like try to find the month like the follows
const expMonth = moment(new Date(Date)).month()

it returns 11 rather 0 which indicates dec rather jan. So, how do I consistently handle this. My users may be using the app in different countries so this should work properly.
By the way, I know moment is depreciated but that's not my concern right now.
